# I am having trouble installing rubies with a multi-user RVM installation

Tags: ruby, rvm, ubuntu-10.04

I followed the instructions on the RVM website on how to do a multi-user installation.  When I try installing a version of ruby, I get the following:

```
$ /usr/local/rvm$ rvm install 1.9.2
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #downloading ruby-1.9.2-p290, this may take a while depending on your connection...
Warning: Failed to create the file ruby-1.9.2-p290.tar.bz2
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0 8604k    0  2804    0     0    631      0  3:52:43  0:00:04  3:52:39   631
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 2804)
ERROR: There was an error, please check /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/*.log. Next we'll try to fetch via http.
Trying http:// URL instead.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file ruby-1.9.2-p290.tar.bz2
  0 8604k    0  2503    0     0   5039      0  0:29:08 --:--:--  0:29:08  9972
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 2503)
ERROR: There was an error, please check /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/*.log
ERROR: There has been an error while trying to fetch the source.  
Halting the installation.
ERROR: There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried using rvmsudo rvm install 1.9.2

Comment: This looks like it is working!  I tried rvmsudo imporperly before, using 'rvmsudo install 1.9.2.'  Silly mistake.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: i am gonna give it as an actual answer, can you accept it?

Comment: Yes, this is definitely an answer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

have you tried using

```
rvmsudo rvm install 1.9.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same problem without any **sudo** stuff, which is not recommendable at all, using the solution of upisdown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638885/running-into-issues-with-rvm-during-ruby-install-1-9-2)