# Installing Ruby 1.9.2 via rvm. Ubuntu 11.10 Problems

Tags: ubuntu-11.10

I have installed 1.8.3 version but when I trying to install Ruby 1.9.2 via rvm see some ERRORS .

I used Google, used many methods to solve this problem but I have not received any any answers. Can anybody help me?

I quote the part of code(in Terminal) below

```
unforbiddenyet@Trash-PC:~$ rvm install 1.9.2

0Warning:      Failed to create the file yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz: Access is denied


Database file /usr/share/ruby-rvm/config/packages does not exist.

0Warning: Failed to create the file ruby-1.9.2-p290.tar.bz2: Denied Warning: Access

curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 2503)
There was an error, please check /usr/share/ruby-rvm/log//*.log. Next we'll try to fetch via http.

0Warning: Failed to create the file ruby-1.9.2-p290.tar.bz2: Denied Warning: Access

Failed writing body (0 != 2804)
There was an error, please check /usr/share/ruby-rvm/log//*.log


There has been an error while trying to fetch the source.  
Halting the installation.
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: Similar problem as http://stackoverflow.com/q/7638885/422353? Seems like rvm was installed as root and now you can't install ruby as a regular user.

Comment: Did you start with the [single user or the multiuser installation](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) ?

Answer (score 1):

To create the packages, first install `1.8.7` and then to install the current version (currently `1.9.3`):

```
$ rvm install 1.8.7
$ rvm install 1.9.3
```